# Develop iOS Apps without a Mac

Tags: ios, macos

I want to create a mobile application for iPhone in Objective-C. The app should be equipped with a graphical user interface.
The problem is that I don't have a Mac computer so I have no access to the Xcode environment.
Is there any possibility to build my project with an online service (for example on a virtual server, remote control etc.) or can I use tools completely under Windows?

Comment: Also you should change your question from compile to develop in. Compile is a whole different thing from what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VirtualMacOSX.com](http://virtualmacosx.com/index.php/xcode-plans) have an offer for xCode development, from (as of now) $10 a month.
 I am sure others have too.

Comment: While this is interesting you are only allowed three hours development time at the lowest tier

Comment: @waf, yes. But 3 hours a day may not be so bad, the price is very low. You could to a lot of preparation and testing locally too, before hitting xCode on the remote Mac.

Comment: And it looks like it is not time limited if you pay $15/month.

Answer (score 0):

Although not optimal you can run mac osx on vmware (on your windows machine), then install xcode on that. I did this for a while until I decided to bite the bullet and I bought a mac

Comment: Please note that you can't run Mac OS on a PC without violating the license.

Comment: Good point, thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Could a license be purchased for running on vmware or virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do it, anyway you will need access to Mac computer (remote or physical, no difference).